# Review Work: Find the area between two curves

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

## Scratch Work

Here's the two equations:
$$x = 2y - y^2$$
$$x = y^2 - 4y$$

I was not given any interval so I determined them by calculating the point on the two functions where the rate of change was zero by taking the derivative of the functions and evaluating for zero like so:

#### Right Function

$$\phi = 2y - y^2$$
$$\phi' = 2 - 2y$$
$$0 = \phi' = 2 - 2y$$
$$2y = 2$$
$$y = 1$$
Yielding:
$$\phi(1) = 2(1) - (1)^2$$
$$\phi(1) = 1$$

#### Left Function

$$\psi = y^2 - 4y$$
$$\psi' = 2y - 4$$
$$0 = \psi' = 2y - 4$$
$$4 = 2y$$
$$y = 2$$
Yielding:
$$\psi(2) = (2)^2 - 4(2)$$
$$\psi(2) = -4$$
This gave me the interval from $[-4,1]$. From there I set up the integral with right function minus the left function
$$\int_{-4}^{1}((2y - y^2) - (y^2 - 4y))dy$$
$$\int_{-4}^{1}(6y - 2y^2)dy$$
$$2\int_{-4}^{1}(3y - y^2)dy$$
And solved for the integral:
$$2(\frac{3y^2}{2} - \frac{2y^3}{3})$$
$$(3y^2 - \frac{2y^3}{3})|_{-4}^{1}$$
$$(3 - \frac{2}{3}) - (48 - \frac{-128}{3})$$
$$\frac{7}{3} - \frac{272}{3}$$
$$= \frac{-265}{3}$$

The online assignment keeps saying this answer is wrong though. Have I done something wrong and not realize it or is it wrong? The site is known to have errors from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curves intersect when

$$2y-y^2=y^2-4y$$

$\implies y=0 $ and $y=3$.

thus, the area between them is

$$|2\int_0^3(y^2-3y)dy|=|18-27|=9$$

Comment: Oooh that makes sense. Turned out that was correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It isnt a must that where they meet is a critical point or local minima,maxima. You can get the limits by equalizing both equations and getting the solutions as $0,3$ and then proceeding with the integration.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are confused by the "area between the curves". Usually when there is no *naturally enclosed* area between two curves, you are explicitly given the range in which you have to find the area *between* the two curves.
But in this case, there is a *naturally enclosed* area (draw the two curves!); so the range of the integration is the points of intersection of the two curves.[image: plot]